# Best way to write bootstrapping in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, random, statistics-bootstrap

I was programming a method that applied statistical bootstrapping over a sample in python, and I have come with two solutions, one which is fully vectorized, and other that uses list comprehension.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample = np.array([80,75,91,97,88,77,94])

bs_sample_1 = np.random.choice(sample,size = (10000,7)).mean(axis = 1)

bs_sample_2 = np.array([np.random.choice(sample,size = 7).mean() for i in range(10000)])

plt.figure()
sns.distplot(sample)

plt.figure()
sns.distplot(bs_sample_1)

plt.figure()
sns.distplot(bs_sample_2)
```

I don't have much knowledge about RNG, but I not sure if the two operations are equally valid to generate bootstrap samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually bootstrapping methods are applied in fitting routines and not on a single array. Also you are calling random.choice to choose 7 elements out of an array of 7 elements which is a bit no sense.

Bootstrapping in curve fitting is applied like this:

1. Given n samples (x,y) with a know uncertainty of y. The uncertainty on y might be given by the instrument or by calculating the std of many consecutive measurements of y.
2. Fit with a certain function let's say f(x,a,b) where a and b are the parameters we want to extract, the values x, y. Save the results of a and b obtained by the fitting procedure.
3. Generate n samples of y* values. Each y* is generated using a Gaussian distribution with the same mean value of the corresponding y and with a sigma as the one given at point 1. (The sigma values might be equal for all points or different depending on corresponding x value). Fit with the same procedure described in point 2. the values x,y* and save the parameters a and b obtained by the fitting routine.
4. Iterate point 3 as many times as you want (typically 1000 or more times). You will end up with many values for the parameters a and b.
5. At this point you can say that the best a-b values describing your function y = f(x,a,b) are the mean value of the may parameters a and b obtained previously and you can say that theyr uncertainty is given by the std of those values. You can also take a look at the distribution of a and b and make further considerations.

In your code you are just calculating the mean value of the 7 elements in the array many many times. But since the "mean value of the mean value" is the mean value on the hole dataset you just end up with the mean of those 7 elements (hope this makes sense).

Ideally bootstrapping means that you generate simulated data based on the known distribution of each of them and than use this data to calculate some quantity at every different generation. Then you can calculate the mean value and std of the quantities obtained.

Comment: `np.random.choice` samples with replacement ([numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)), so the OPs code does actually do as intended.